# MAUI How to pass the view model to a control in a page

Tags: maui

I have this content page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TimeApp.ViewModels"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:TimeApp.Controls.Wizard"
             x:Class="TimeApp.Views.EnrolamientoPage"
             x:DataType="vm:EnrolamientoViewModel"
             Title="Enrolamiento">
    <StackLayout Padding="25" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <controls:MyCustomControl VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BindingContext="{Binding Path=.}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

See the `MyCustomControl` control. I need to pass the instantiated binding context to it (the view model).

Now I can only pass a property belonging to the view model, and I need to pass the whole view model.

Is it possible?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything.  By default it should inherit the `BindingContext` of its parent.

Comment: To clarify: REMOVE `BindingContext="{Binding Path=.}"`.

Comment: Hello.. the problem was that the `MyCustomControl` constructor was being called before the page constructor. I don't know why this happens. I needed the context in `MyCustomControl` constructor, but it was assigned in the page constructor. I have changed some logic so I need the context after the page constructor was called.

Comment: You should never assume a property is set in the constructor.  You can use the OnBindingContextChanged event to execute code once the BindingContext has been set

Answer (score 0):

You could use `OnBindingContextChanged` event as Jason said

```
public MyCustomControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContextChanged += MyCustomControl_BindingContextChanged;
}
```

Get the BindingContext:

```
private void MyCustomControl_BindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EnrolamientoViewModel viewModel = this.BindingContext as EnrolamientoViewModel;
}
```

or override `OnBindingContextChanged` method in ContentView code behind

```
protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
{
    base.OnBindingContextChanged();
    var context = BindingContext as EnrolamientoViewModel;
}
```

Hope it works.